# How to install and play Roblox with Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: games

⚠I'm sorry, I do not understand English so much, so I am google translate.

I want to do Roblox with Ubuntu 17.10, but I can not play with wine.

Please tell me how to do it

Answer (score 3):

ROBLOX is incompatible with Wine and PlayOnLinux.

Try using a virtual machine (VMWare or VirtualBox) and run Windows in a VM.